# Issue with background image

Tags: android

I try to create background with full screen image, but only have a grey square.

[image]

**The correc timage:** 
[image]

I add image in project using the new/image Asset of android studio.

**activity layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/mainbackground"
        tools:context="com.imagenia.rollaction.rollaction.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Al menu"
            android:id="@+id/boton"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest** // I change the theme

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActividadPrincipal"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">


    </activity>
</application>
```

**EDIT**

I try add directly png file, in android image button. but have a sema issue, the image button are grey square.

Comment: Are you using png image?

Comment: Yes, Android studio change my jpeg to png file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding the image directly into the the res/drawable folder. Copy from the origin and paste it directly into the drawable folder. It should work. The code seems correct. It should load the background image.

Comment: Thanks, Issue is in import withs new image asset

Answer (score 0):

To create a button with the custom background you can use Android `TextView` instead of the `Button` and use `android:background` attribute for button image and `android:text` for button text.